# Processing input files

Tags: tex-core, external-files

What is the easiest technique to get the n-th line from a input file called `input` and pass it on to a macro called `\process`. Please note that I'm not asking about outputing the n-th line verbatim but about catching the line and passing it on to the macro. The macro `\process` is defined as follows:

```
\def\process#1\endprocess{%
    % process #1
}
```

The n-th line of the input file should be passed as the argument `#1` to the macro `\process`.

Comment: @werner The `external-files` tag is good. Thanks for providing it. The `input` tag, which I added in a related thread, was removed twice:-)

Comment: Now that you mention it, `input` seems to be inappropriate here since you're not actually using (or requesting the use of) `\input`, but you're processing part of an `external-file`.

Comment: @werner I agree that `input` isn't so good.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
\makeatletter
\newread\dongen@in
\newcommand{\dongenprocess}[2]{% #1=file name, #2=line to read
  \begingroup\endlinechar=\m@ne
  \openin\dongen@in=#1\relax
  \count@=\z@
  \loop\ifnum\count@<#2\relax
    \ifeof\dongen@in
      \ERROR
    \else
      \read\dongen@in to \@tempa
    \fi
    \advance\count@\@ne
  \repeat
  \ifx\@tempa\@empty\ERROR\fi
  \closein\dongen@in
  \expandafter\endgroup
  \expandafter\process\@tempa\endprocess
}
\makeatother
```

If you try to get past the end of the file you'll get some errors; of course you can define `\ERROR` as you wish, for example providing a fallback. I assume that lines are not empty. The second `\ERROR` corresponds to the empty line that TeX implicitly assumes at the end of a file.

Basically, I do a loop reading one line at a time until reaching the desired one. Then `\@tempa` (expanded) is passed to `\process`.

Call it as

```
\dongenprocess{dongen.dat}{2}
```

to read the second line.

Here is a possible LaTeX3 implementation:

```
\usepackage{xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\dongenprocess}{mm}
  {
   \group_begin: \tex_endlinechar:D \c_minus_one
   \ior_open:Nn \l_dongen_read_s { #1 }
   \prg_replicate:nn {#2}
     {
      \ior_if_eof:NTF \l_dongen_read_s
       { \dongen_error: }
       { \ior_to:NN \l_dongen_read_s \l_dongen_read_tl }
     }
   \ior_close:N \l_dongen_read_s
   \tl_if_empty:NT \l_dongen_read_tl { \dongen_error: }
   \exp_args:NNo \group_end: \dongen_process:n { \l_dongen_read_tl }
  }

\ior_new:N \l_dongen_read_s
\tl_new:N \l_dongen_read_tl
\cs_new:Npn \dongen_process:n #1 { \process#1\endprocess }
\cs_new:Npn \dongen_error: { \tl_set:Nn \l_dongen_read_tl { INEXISTENT~LINE } }
\ExplSyntaxOff
```

EDIT: alternative version of `\dongenprocess` that trims spaces around the input read from the file

```
\NewDocumentCommand{\dongenprocess}{mm}
  {
   \group_begin:
   \ior_open:Nn \l_dongen_read_s { #1 }
   \prg_replicate:nn {#2}
     { 
      \ior_if_eof:NTF \l_dongen_read_s 
       { \dongen_error: }
       { \ior_to:NN \l_dongen_read_s \l_dongen_read_tl }
     }
   \ior_close:N \l_dongen_read_s
   \tl_trim_spaces:N \l_dongen_read_tl
   \tl_if_in:NnT \l_dongen_read_tl { \par } { \dongen_error: }
   \exp_args:NNo \group_end: \dongen_process:n { \l_dongen_read_tl }
  }
```

Comment: Thanks. Looks like an easy enough solution for a file processing toolkit. I've uppped your score but I'll wait a bit longer before I choose the/some best solution.

Comment: I like the elegance of the naming convention of the macros: `\dongenprocess`, `\l_dongen_read_tl`, ...